# Is there a way to create label on workflow run?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using GitHub Actions workflow to do product release. I'd like to record the date each time any workflow deployed to production environment. GitHub Actions doesn't offer a good UI to view the workflow runs based on date/time. For example, I'd like to get all workflow runs on 2024-01-01.

So I am thinking to create a date label from action job to attach the label to the workflow run, but I couldn't find any way to do that.

Is it possible to do that in GitHub? If not, would there be any alternative option to achieve similar result?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're aiming to achieve. The list of workflow runs in GitHub actions shows when the workflow was run on the right side (relative to the current date, e.g. "last week").

Comment: but it is not easy to search by date. For example, I'd like to know what workflow run on a particular date

Comment: Are you willing to run your workflow in a specific time? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule

Comment: not really. The workflow is triggered manually. The label I am looking for is for history review. we can review any history deployment by date.

Comment: You could use the [GitHub API for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions?apiVersion=2022-11-28)?

Comment: I already checked them but it doesn't have api to create label on workflow runs.